# Converting georeferenced jpgs to geotiff and image is shifted/warped

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, jpg

I have hundreds of georeferenced jpgs in ArcMap 10 that I need to convert to geotiffs.

I'm trying to use GDAL translate to create geotiffs from them.  Everything works great except that the resultant geotiff is slightly shifted/warped.

Can anyone suggest how to convert georeferenced jpgs to geotiffs without this shift/warp?

My GDAL command to create this geotiff was:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff input_file.jpg output file.tif
```

Gdaltranslate indicates exactly the same coordinate system and bounding coordinates between the jpg and the geotiff. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With Google or Openstreetmap background, the original jpg is about 300metres off the correct position. Thats far more than the shift between NAD27 and NAD83.

So you have three opportunities:

1) ask the data provider how they georeferenced the photos.

2) if the shift is constantly througout all imagery, you can create a custom CRS (in Arcgis: custom datum transformation) with the same ellipsoid and play with the +towgs84 parametres until the photos align.

2) throw away everything but the .jpg file and do the georeferencing again on your own.